# C# - declare constant fields, but organize with interface?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of constant values for several types of "buildings", the sizes of which are fixed (due to the 3D model they will hold).

I've looked around and read about base classes, interfaces and abstracts, but couldn't really grasp the concepts completely. However I really liked the idea of using interfaces to "organize" classes with common fields. In this case, sizeX and sizeY is a type of field shared across all building classes.

```
public static class BuildingProperties {

public class House
{
    public const int sizeX = 4;
    public const int sizeY = 4;
}

public class House1
{
    public const int sizeX = 6;
    public const int sizeY = 6;
}

public class Commercial
{
    public const int sizeX = 10;
    public const int sizeY = 10;
}

}
```

Is there some way I can implement an interface for this, without the need for constructors in each class? (I would like to simply call for these constants as required, like so:)

```
public void program()
{
    int sizeX = BuildingProperties.House.sizeX;
}
```

And for future use, if I needed to add another field (for example "height"), I would like the compiler to throw an error and say "hey! you forgot to give House1 a "height" value!

Is there something like this that someone can point me towards?

Comment: What if you just declare the sub-classes (e.g. House) static as well?

Comment: My previous comment regarded your expected syntax in the program above. For compiler to throw errors 'No height value for House1', you'd have to create an interface or a base class, and inherit it in your models. Then you'd _have_ to initialize instances of those classes since static properties can't be overridden or specified in constructors

Comment: Never use public fields - use getter only properties! You can use them inside an interface as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like your code need some re-design. I don't see why you would want to have all these public sub classes. Instead, I would just use one class for all building types (assuming the all always have the same properties) and 3 properties for that class's type:

```
public class Building
{
    public Building(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        SizeX = sizeX;
        SizeY = sizeY;
    }

    public int SizeX { get; }
    public int SizeY { get; }
}

public static class BuildingProperties
{

    public static Building House { get; } = new Building(4, 4);

    public static Building House1 { get; } = new Building(6, 6);

    public static Building Commercial { get; } = new Building(10, 10);

}
```

Note that all the properties are immutable in this code sample, and also, if you add a property in the future, and would like to get compiler errors when it's missing, all you have to do is change the constructor of the `Building` class to acccept another parameter for this new readonly property.

Comment: Obviously the OP didn't share the entire codebase of each class, it's safe to assume they differ in more than the values of the `const`s

Comment: @haim770 I'm not so sure about that. It seems to me more a result of a poor code design.

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: @ZoharPeled, If that was the case, then there's no need for a `class` at all, you can end up with a simple `struct` to represent those values. Also, the OP wanted to be able to access the sizes of each type in a static way (without the need to instantiate it).

Comment: @haim770 structs would probably be a better choise then classes here, you are correct. however, note that my sample is also a static class with static properties...

Comment: Yeah also, `sizeX` and `sizeY` is messy. Better use `Point` instead.

Comment: As I see it, the question was *how can I expose some data from each type in a static way (`const`/`static`) and still be able to force each of those (and future) types to provide those values*. Suggesting `Point` or static factories has nothing to do with the problem. Nice approach though.

Comment: My code sample was an attempt to create a better code with minimal changes. therefor, I kept sizeX and sizeY, while I'm well aware or the `Size` struct (that's semantically better to use then `Point` here). that's also the reason I used a class and not a struct.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Getting rid of 3 classes is far from "minimal changes". They can easily represent 3 business entities with real logic inside them (and can end up in a database mapped to different tables). But again, if you're right and their only purpose was to hold the `sizeX/Y` values then it's indeed a poor design and your approach is better.

Comment: @haim770 well said. I guess we will have to wait for the OP to know the true meaning of those classes :-).

Comment: Learning a lot of stuff from this, thanks guys! Originally I only really needed to hold sizeX/Y values - apologies for the poor design, as I am still stumbling my way through learning OOP.

Thanks to you guys I get to do some more research and learn a bit more! Thanks for the responses, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create an interface that will declare 2 getter properties:

```
public interface IProvideSizes
{
    int SizeX { get; }
    int SizeY { get; }
}
```

And in your classes have them return the data from your `const`:

```
public class House : IProvideSizes
{
    public const int _sizeX = 4;
    public const int _sizeY = 4;

    public int SizeX { get { return _sizeX; } }
    public int SizeY { get { return _sizeY; } }
}

public class House1 : IProvideSizes
{
    public const int _sizeX = 6;
    public const int _sizeY = 6;

    public int SizeX { get { return _sizeX; } }
    public int SizeY { get { return _sizeY; } }
}

public class Commercial : IProvideSizes
{
    public const int _sizeX = 10;
    public const int _sizeY = 10;

    public int SizeX { get { return _sizeX; } }
    public int SizeY { get { return _sizeY; } }
}
```

This way you can preserve and maintain the contract of each type, while still being able to access each type's specific size in a static way (without the need to instantiate it).

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered a dictionary?

```
            Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Point> properties = new Dictionary<string, System.Drawing.Point>() {
                {"House", new System.Drawing.Point(4,4)},
                {"House1", new System.Drawing.Point(6,6)},
                {"Commercial", new System.Drawing.Point(10,10)}
            };
```